# Get first and last word in element's text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In JavaScript, how can I get the first and last words from an element's text?

For example:

```
<div class="content">this is a test</div>// output 'this' 'test'
<p>This is another test</p>// output 'this' 'test'
```

How can I do that? I am not sure how to use RegExp to match them.

Comment: You can loop through the element's text nodes and append their `data` to a string. From there, it would be safe to run a RegExp pattern and get your answer.

Comment: You need to be more specific what your definition of "word" is. If the element text is `This is a test.` is the last word `test` or `test.`? What if the element text is `你好`? Is the last word `好`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex with combined with `replace()` in Javascript

```
/([a-z]+) .* ([a-z]+)/i
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e8yZd/2/

Comment: Sorry? It doesn't seem to be like that. At least not in my browser. It does however add a `<br>` tag after showing the first and last words from the `<div>` tag because I wrote the Javascript to do it like so, that way it's a little easier to read the result data. Or perhaps I misunderstood you?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/e8yZd/3/. Your code doesn't perform a **match**, but uses a replace. "this<br> is ..." starts matching at "is .." using RE `/[a-z] .* [a-z]/`, because the first word isn't immediately followed by a whitespace (` `). A dot, comma or anything similar will also break your code.

Comment: @Rob W aah that...right. Simply remove the first whitespace should fix the problem I guess. But then again, I wouldn't exactly know whether if the OP has the first word followed by a tag like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
getFirstAndLastWords("this is a test"); // Outputs: "this test"

function getFirstAndLastWords(text) {
  var text_arr = text.split(" ");
  return text_arr[0] + " " + text_arr[text_arr.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid parsing html with regex. Look at this SO answer [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You can use this regex

```
var x = '<p>test test1</p>'.replace(/(<[^>]*>)/g,'').split(' ')
```

x[0] will  be first word, x[x.length-1] will be last element

Answer (score 0):

Better with elements than html.

```
var text=(element.textContent || element.innerText).match(/\w+/g) ||[];
alert(text[0]+'\n'+text.pop());
```